# How to write ListItem Version Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

In my project I need to migrate the List/DocumentList data along with its version history. I am able to migrate List/DocumentList using CSOM. But not getting solution to write the version data at destination. 
How can I upload the version data at destination using CSOM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSOM code to migrate files with versions:

```
int fileCount = sourceFolder.Files.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
 {
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sourceFile = sourceFolder.Files[i];
    FileVersionCollection sourceFileVersions = sFile.Versions; 
    sContext.Load(sourceFileVersions, fileVersions => fileVersions.Include( version => version.Url, version => version.VersionLabel, version => version.CheckInComment )); 
    try { 
            sContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            //handle exception   
    }


    foreach (FileVersion fileVer in sourceFileVersions)
    { 
        UploadFiles(sContext.Url + "/" + fileVer.Url, targetFolder, sourceItem["FileLeafRef"].ToString());
    }
}

private static void UploadFiles(string sourceFileUrl, Folder targetFolder, string fileName)
 {
     FileCreationInformation targetFileVersionCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
     targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Overwrite = true; 
     try { 
     WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(sourceFileUrl); 
     request.Credentials = sContext.Credentials; 
     using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        { using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] verBuffer = new byte[32768]; 
                using (MemoryStream versionMS = new MemoryStream())
                    { 
                    int read; 
                    while ((read = stream.Read(verBuffer, 0, verBuffer.Length)) > 0) { 
                        versionMS.Write(verBuffer, 0, read); 
                    } 
                    versionMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    targetFileVersionCreationInfo.ContentStream = versionMS; 
                    tContext.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite; 
                    targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Url = targetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileName; 
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File targetVersionFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(targetFileVersionCreationInfo);
                    try { 
                        tContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
                    } catch (Exception ex) { 
                    //handle exception   
                    } 
                } 
            }
        } 
     } catch (Exception ex) { 
     //handle exception   
     }
 }
```

Read the following blog for more information:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakhiguha/2015/12/06/migrate-sharepoint-document-with-version-to-sharepoint-online-using-csom/